# Using "grep -n" and echo : : double backslash interpreted

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I want to get the line number of the pattern "`\label`" with "`grep -n`" into a file.

The file content is :

```
\begin{equation}
(\beq{f'_{i}})_{3}-(\beq{e_{i}})_{3}=\text{d}\delta\,\beq{e_{i}}-\delta\,\text{d}\beq{e_{i}}
\label{r58}
\end{equation}

...

\begin{align}
&\beq{mm'_{3}}-\beq{mm_{3}}=\text{d}\delta\,\beq{m}-\delta\,\text{d}\beq{m} 
\label{r59} \\
&(\beq{e'_{i}})_{3}-(\beq{e_{i}})_{3}=\text{d}\delta\,\beq{e_{i}}-\delta\,\text{d}\beq{e_{i}}
\label{r60}
\end{align}

...

\begin{equation}
(\beq{g'_{i}})_{3}-(\beq{e_{i}})_{3}=\text{d}\delta\,\beq{e_{i}}-\delta\,\text{d}\beq{e_{i}}
\label{r61}
\end{equation}

...
```

The command that I use :

```
for k in $(grep -n '\\label' test.tex); do echo $k; done
```

and I get :

```
...
    1366:\label{r58}
    1376:\label{r59}
    \\
    1378:\label{r60}
    1388:\label{r61}
...
```

and I want :

```
...
    1366:\label{r58}
    1376:\label{r59}
    1378:\label{r60}
    1388:\label{r61}
...
```

Given that I handle after the value of `k variable`, I would like to skip the line with a double backslash, it seems that "`grep -n`" interprets the double backslash.

I know that I could do a pipe command on `k` like "`grep -v '\\\\`' but can I directly skip this double backslash with `grep -n` (with an additional flag or with a more explicit pattern) ?

Thanks

Comment: If you can use perl this could be a solution:
`perl -ne 'print "$.:$1 \n" if /(\\label{.*})(.*)/' c.txt`

I did just some quick tests so maybe you have to tune the regexp a bit.

Comment: How about another grep in between - 
`for k in $(grep -n '\\label' file_grep); do echo $k | grep '\\label'; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue with the newline with

```
$ for k in "$(grep -n '\\label' text.tex)"; do echo "$k"; done
3:\label{r58}
10:\label{r59} \\
12:\label{r60}
19:\label{r61}
```

i.e., quoting the command substitution. Which is a very complicated (and not recommended) way of just using

```
grep -n '\\label' test.tex
```

as it seems.

If you don't quote the command substitution, its result undergoes word splitting and the `\\` is seen as a separate element to loop over, that's why it gets its own line.

To just get the parts you want, you can use

```
$ grep -on '\\label{[^}]*}' test.tex
3:\label{r58}
10:\label{r59}
12:\label{r60}
19:\label{r61}
```

`-o` to just retain the match, and the regex matches the braces after `\label` as well.

Comment: Never do this: for x in $(command) or `command` or $var. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. "${names[@]}") or a while-read 
                loop (eg. while read -r line). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'm not recommending doing it like this, I'm merely showing why OP has spurious newlines in his output.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged with Bash, I assume you're using the Bash shell.

The following code will take `input_file.txt` as an input file, and create `output_file.txt` containing a list of line numbers matching your pattern.

```
while read -r line;do printf '%s\n' "${line%%:*}";done < <(grep -n --fixed-strings '\label' input_file.txt) > output_file.txt
```

**P.S.**

Regarding the code you posted in the question:
Never do this: `for x in $(command)` or `command` or $var. for-in is used for iterating arguments, not (output) strings. Instead, use a glob (eg. *.txt), arrays (eg. `"${names[@]}"`) or a while-read 
                loop (eg. `while read -r line`). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor